# Unable to locate local file in @INC, not CPANable

Tags: perl, cygwin, installation

I'm am currently trying to download a program that has given me many issues. I'm running cygwin on Windows. The program should run correctly and the installation packages were all installed in an administrator terminal shell, and as the program was being un'tar'ed no errors were thrown. However after the installation the program cannot find the @INC module named FASTA in the file system

```
rpbas@DESKTOP-4LMFDCK /cygdrive/c/Users/rpbas/Documents/Work/OliveraLab/signal-4.1 
$ ./signal -t euk -f short test/euk10.fsa > euk10.fsa.short_out Can't locate FASTA.pm in @INC (you may need to install the FASTA module) 
(@INC contains: 
/cygdrive/c/Users/rpbas/Documents/Work/Olivera\ Lab/signal-4.1/lib 
\cygdrive\c\Users\rpbas\Documents\Work\Olivera/ Lab\signal-4.1 
/usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.26/x86_64-cygwin-threads 
/usr/local/share/perl5/site_perl/5.26 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.26/x86_64-cygwin-threads 
/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/5.26 
/usr/lib/perl5/5.26/x86_64-cygwin-threads /usr/share/perl5/5.26) 
at ./signal line 60. 
BEGIN failed-- compilation aborted at ./signal line 60.
```

However, the ./lib/FASTA.pm file clearly exists and being directed to.

```
rpbas@DESKTOP-4LMFDCK /cygdrive/c/Users/rpbas/Documents/Work/Olivera\ Lab/signal-4.1/lib
$ ls
FASTA.pm
```

The code includes the line (at the beginning)

```
BEGIN {
$ENV{SIGNAL} = '/cygdrive/c/Users/rpbas/Documents/Work/Olivera\ Lab/signal-4.1';
}
```

and at line 60

```
use lib "$ENV{SIGNAL}/lib";
use FASTA;
```

I've been working on this issue for a couple of days now and it a big bottleneck to the other parts of my program. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are getting tripped up by the quote interpolation rules of Perl. Inside single quotes, a backslash character only acts as an "escape" character when it is followed by a single quote or by another backslash. In all other cases, it is interpreted as a literal backslash.

If you printed out `$ENV{SIGNAL}` you would see something like

```
/cygdrive/c/Users/rpbas/Documents/Work/Olivera\ Lab/signal-4.1
```

including the backslash character. Don't escape the space and you should be all right.

```
BEGIN {
    $ENV{SIGNAL} = 
        '/cygdrive/c/Users/rpbas/Documents/Work/Olivera Lab/signal-4.1';
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I hadn't worked with perl much before this project. Things like that escape me (haha...)

Answer (score 0):

`@INC` contains

```
/cygdrive/c/Users/rpbas/Documents/Work/Olivera\ Lab/signal-4.1/lib
```

when it should contain

```
/cygdrive/c/Users/rpbas/Documents/Work/Olivera Lab/signal-4.1/lib
```

You could replace

```
BEGIN {
  $ENV{SIGNAL} = '/cygdrive/c/Users/rpbas/Documents/Work/Olivera\ Lab/signal-4.1';
}

use lib "$ENV{SIGNAL}/lib";
```

with

```
BEGIN {
  $ENV{SIGNAL} = '/cygdrive/c/Users/rpbas/Documents/Work/Olivera Lab/signal-4.1';
}

use lib "$ENV{SIGNAL}/lib";
```

but a better solution is to replace it with

```
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );
use lib ( $ENV{SIGNAL} || $RealBin ) . "/lib";
```